# IONIC Controller, Unable to access cordova plugin ThemableBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**Error: Refernce Error Cordova not defined**

> Below is my Controller,

```
controller("FeedController", function($http, $scope,$rootScope) {

cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', {

    backButton: {
        wwwImage: 'images/back.png',
        wwwImagePressed: 'images/back_pressed.png',
        wwwImageDensity: 2,
        align: 'left',
        event: 'backPressed'
    }

});

});
```

Comment: this won't work in "ionic serve" try testing it on the mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Cannot Access Device Plugins in Web Commands ,

- ionic serve
- ionic serve --lab

or Something else , You Have to try it On real time device ...

try

> ionic run android